# using after method with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

As was suggested, I started to use .after method to create bouncing ball GUI, and again an into a problem.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
import random


class Widg:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.geometry('600x500+200+150')
        canvas = Canvas(master)
        canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        oval = canvas.create_oval(1, 1, 11, 11, fill='green')

        def call_func(self):
            for i in range(3):
                rand_x = random.randint(1, 50)
                rand_y = random.randint(1, 50)
                canvas.move(oval, rand_x, rand_y)
                canvas.after(500)
                print('x= ', rand_x)
                print('y= ', rand_y)

        canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', call_func)


def main():

    root = Tk()

    a = Widg(root)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And again, when I start it, it runs behind the widget and simply shows the final result. (No animation)

upd.: 
upd2.: @ tobias_k  duly noted! Won't happen again! Thanks for your answers!

Comment: It looks like your call to `after` is missing some parameters. And maybe its called at the wrong time.

Comment: According to the book:
You can also omit the callback. If you do, this method simply waits for the given number of milliseconds, without serving any events (same as time.sleep(delay_ms*0.001)).
So basically, w.after(500) should work, no?

Comment: @DEN_VER (1) Please don't just modify your code, but post an updated version _below_ the original code so existing answers don't get invalidated; (2) to request feedback from an answerer, comment below their answer, not below the question, so they get notified (I just came back by chance); (3) you still did not fix the call to `after`.

Comment: @ tobias_k 
Thank you, I returned it back. You were right, now it works.

Comment: @tobias_k: `after(500)` is identical to calling sleep, and does just what the name "sleep" implies: it puts the entire GUI to sleep. You should never do this because the GUI can't process _any_ events, including requests to refresh the display.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the function to call in `after` -- in your case, the same function it was called in. As noted [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863227/using-after-method-with-tkinter/48864236#comment84779128_48863227), without a callback function, `after` acts just like `sleep` (except the argument is in milliseconds instead of seconds), i.e. it will wait for the given time, but in doing so will block the UI, such that no inputs are registered, and particularly the ball is not redrawn until after the loop. By calling `after` with the callback, you indefinitely call the function again, each time repositioning and redrawing the ball.

Also, note that the parameter to `call_func` is *not* `self` (as it was in the original code) -- it is not a method of the class, but a nested function -- but the `event` issued by the mouse click. You should make this a default-parameter as there will be no event when using `after` (and you don't need it either). Also, there seems to be no need to the loop; if you want the ball to move faster, reduce the time in `after`, and there is no point in using `self` for the `rand_x/y` variables.

```
def call_func(event=None):
    rand_x = random.randint(-50, 50)
    rand_y = random.randint(-50, 50)
    self.canvas.move(self.oval, rand_x, rand_y)
    self.canvas.after(150, call_func)
```

If you want the function to be called back only a limited number of times, you could add another parameter, keeping track of the number of repeats:

```
def call_func(event=None, repeat=10):
    rand_x = random.randint(-50, 50)
    rand_y = random.randint(-50, 50)
    self.canvas.move(self.oval, rand_x, rand_y)
    if repeat:
        self.canvas.after(150, lambda: call_func(repeat=repeat-1))
```